# Python dict.append in for loop adds last value as append for all

Tags: python

I'm trying to append a list of bank transactions. These contain 12 transactions, and I want that to be 100k+. Normally that wouldn't be an issue, but this time I'm somehow doing something wrong. I'm setting a single transaction as "example", and simply changing 3 values to something random:

```
# Set any transaction that can be updated with random values
transaction = df.accounts[0]['transactions'][0]

# Randomizing any amount of transactions and appending them to the dataframe
for i in range(10):
    rand = round(random.uniform(-25000, 25000), 2)
    res = transaction
    res['transactionDate'] = random_date("2/22/2021 1:30 PM", "2/22/2022 4:50 AM", random.random())
    res['classifyCategory'] = categories[round(random.random() * len(categories)) - 1]
    res['amount'] = rand

    print(res)

    df.accounts[0]['transactions'].append(res)
```

This returns the following:

```
amount: -8664.93, date: 05/02/2021 11:43 AM, categorie: a
amount: -7433.14, date: 04/15/2021 01:51 PM, categorie: b
amount: 3905.45, date: 02/20/2022 04:34 AM, categorie: c
amount: -11755.49, date: 04/21/2021 07:44 AM, categorie: d
amount: 17833.53, date: 04/22/2021 07:07 PM, categorie: e
amount: -3694.67, date: 12/26/2021 01:02 PM, categorie: f
amount: 24981.7, date: 01/01/2022 10:25 PM, categorie: g
amount: 14045.01, date: 04/03/2021 06:18 PM, categorie: h
amount: 23642.71, date: 05/01/2021 12:38 PM, categorie: i
amount: 5687.76, date: 09/26/2021 01:41 AM, categorie: j
```

This simply adds 10 transactions with random transaction date, classification and amount. However, only the very last value of what this returns will be added 10 times to the transactions list:

```
amount: 5687.76, date: 09/26/2021 01:41 AM, categorie: j
amount: 5687.76, date: 09/26/2021 01:41 AM, categorie: j
amount: 5687.76, date: 09/26/2021 01:41 AM, categorie: j
amount: 5687.76, date: 09/26/2021 01:41 AM, categorie: j
amount: 5687.76, date: 09/26/2021 01:41 AM, categorie: j
amount: 5687.76, date: 09/26/2021 01:41 AM, categorie: j
amount: 5687.76, date: 09/26/2021 01:41 AM, categorie: j
amount: 5687.76, date: 09/26/2021 01:41 AM, categorie: j
amount: 5687.76, date: 09/26/2021 01:41 AM, categorie: j
amount: 5687.76, date: 09/26/2021 01:41 AM, categorie: j
```

I have no idea what's going wrong here. Does anyone have a clue how only the last value could be added for each item in the loop, even though it shouldn't even have that value when appending the previous ones?

Comment: `res = transaction` you are modifying the same `transaction` in each iteration

Comment: @deadshot I set "res" to be "transaction" every single time, so that the entire transaction is there. I then change some values and append the list with "res", not with "transaction". Does it imply it as "the same", and thus I set transaction through res?

Comment: There is no such thing as `dict.append`. Please provide a [mre]. Your snippet isn't a MRE because it won't run on account of missing variables and functions. What type is `transaction`? If it's a dictionary (or other mutable type) then what deadshot says is correct. When you do `res = transaction`, you're simply saying that `res` references the same object in memory that `transaction` does. You aren't copying anything [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I agree, my apologies. I should have a least given a reproducable example. By And deadshot was indeed correct, plentyofcoffee gave an example of deepcopy that does work. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of `df.accounts[0]['transactions'][0]` after you're done with your loop. It should have the same values as the 10 identical entries you added at the end.

The line `res = transaction` is not copying the dictionary stored in the `transaction` variable; it is pointing the `res` variable to the same underlying dictionary that the `transaction` variable is pointing to.
Likewise, `transaction = df.accounts[0]['transactions'][0]` does not copy the dictionary stored in  `df.accounts[0]['transactions'][0]`; it merely points the `transaction` variable to that dictionary. Thus, any edits to `res` or `transaction` will actually change the dictionary at `df.accounts[0]['transactions'][0]`.

It looks to me like you want to make a deep copy of the underlying dictionary before mutating the copy. This should be closer to what you want:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

# Randomizing any amount of transactions and appending them to the dataframe
for i in range(10):
    rand = round(random.uniform(-25000, 25000), 2)
    # Set any transaction that can be updated with random values
    res = deepcopy(df.accounts[0]['transactions'][0])
    res['transactionDate'] = random_date("2/22/2021 1:30 PM", "2/22/2022 4:50 AM", random.random())
    res['classifyCategory'] = categories[round(random.random() * len(categories)) - 1]
    res['amount'] = rand

    print(res)

    df.accounts[0]['transactions'].append(res)
```

Comment: so it just becomes a copy of the link to the memory address, not it's actual value. That's very interesting information, thanks a lot! Also, your example works like a charm. Deepcopy, going to check what exactly that does and how it works. Thanks, this will save me many times in the future probably!

Comment: Note that if `res` is a dictionary and `transactionDate`, `classifyCategory` and `amount` are the only three keys in your dictionary, you don't even need to do `deepcopy`. Just define a new dictionary like so: `res = dict()`